# Event.target collides only once, not multiple times

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When I run the onCollision function, it seems that it collides with the 'ground' multiple times, even though its not moving. How can I make it so once the object hits the ground, it only collides with it 'once'?

I would like to give a 'score' every time it hits the ground, but because it hits the ground multiple times, my score seems to keep going up.

here is part of the code:

```
function playerCollision( self, event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        --if hit bottom column, u get points
        if event.target.type == "player" and event.other.type == "bottomColumn" then
            print ("hit column")
            onPlatform = true


        else
        --if hit anything else, gameOver
            --composer.gotoScene( "restart" )

            print ("hit ground")
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Showing the relevant code snippets is likely going to be helpful here.

Comment: Alright. I added my post!

Comment: You might want to try [here](https://forums.coronalabs.com/).

Comment: alright thanks! I hope someone can help me out :/

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find anything wrong with your code, just try to add only this statement, hope it may work.

```
function playerCollision( self, event )
   if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    --if hit bottom column, u get points
     if event.target.type == "player" and event.other.type == "bottomColumn" then
        print ("hit column")
        onPlatform = true
        return true -- try adding this 

    else
    --if hit anything else, gameOver
        --composer.gotoScene( "restart" )

        print ("hit ground")
    end
end
```

end

Comment: it seems, even after i put return true, the print statement happens multiple times. Which means, it is colliding with the object multiple times. Is there another option to fix this?